# Is it possible to pass table name as as argument in liquibase changeset?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture, liquibase

> I am excuting liquibase chnageset when spring application starts

```
<changeSet author="kbatra" id="1.2">
        <createTable schemaName="public" tableName="table_a">
            <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)" />
            <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)" />
            <column name="username" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints unique="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="password" type="varchar(1000)" />
            <column name="email" type="varchar(255)" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

> Now what i want is i want to execute same changeSet but with the
>   different table name   is it possible to pass the table name in
>   liquibase as an argument  through spring?  Is there any other to
>   acheive this same scenario?
>
> I am working on one module of spring hibernate application where i
>   have to generate same sql schema structure but with different table
>   name at run time as per the users requirement  if this is not possible
>   through liquibase then how can i acheive this scenario can anyone
>   please help me to design architecture for this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use replaceable parameters in your changeset, and then set those parameters when you deploy the changeset. Your changeset might look like this:

```
<changeSet author="kbatra" id="1.2">
        <createTable schemaName="public" tableName="${USER_TABLE_NAME}">
            <column name="id" autoIncrement="true" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="varchar(255)" />
            <column name="last_name" type="varchar(255)" />
            <column name="username" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints unique="true" />
            </column>
            <column name="password" type="varchar(1000)" />
            <column name="email" type="varchar(255)" />
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
```

And then you would need to set the value of `USER_TABLE_NAME` when you run the liquibase `update` command, which is running when your application starts up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply